# Rearrange the filecontent in UNIX

Tags: text-processing

I need to re-arrange this:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 - Partition Name: testblade012                                 -
 - Type: Shared-SMT-4                                           -
 - Entitled Capacity: 0.30                                      -
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

into this:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 - Partition Name                           : testblade012      -
 - Type                                     : Shared-SMT-4      -
 - Entitled Capacity                        : 0.30              -  
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please post text not an image of text. Thank you.

Comment: I am really sorry, but i tried all the ways to type the above content...              but its not reflecting properly.....  thats why i linked the image....

Comment: @SivasankarC please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) from the [Help Center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: done...   Yes dashes  is also part of output.....

Comment: cat file |sed 's/: /\t:\t/' |column  -s $'\t' -t
ksh: column:  not found.

Comment: Is there a fixed length for the first column in your output (e.g. number of characters from the beginning of line up to the `:`) or should that be calculated based on longest field from first column in the input ?

Comment: Yes, Should be calculated based on longest field from first column in the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `printf`:

```
while IFS=[:] read f1 f2
do
    [ "$f2" ] && printf '%-40s: %-22s-\n' "$f1" "$(echo ${f2%-})" || echo "$f1"
done <<<' ----------------------------------------------------------------
 - Partition Name: testblade012                                 -
 - Type: Shared-SMT-4                                           -
 - Entitled Capacity: 0.30                                      -
 ----------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Or with `awk`

```
awk -F'[:]' '$2{sub(" *-$","",$2);$0=sprintf("%-40s:%-23s-",$1,$2)}1'
```

Comment: Works like a Charm....   You are Awesome.....